# Using JPA @ElementCollection for a String collection from a join table?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I would like my User entity to include a `List<String>` of permissions coming from **user_permission** join table, however getting a multitude of errors using different examples.

Should `ElementCollection` also be able to handle join table as defined below given I indicate which columns to join?

**user table**

- id (pk)
- email

**permission table**

- permission (pk)
- permission_description

**user_permission table**

- email (fk, pk)
- permission (fk, pk)

**User Entity**

```
    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name="permission", nullable=false)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_permission", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "email", referencedColumnName = "email"))
    private List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: class com.abc.data.entity.User cannot be cast to class java.io.Serializable (com.abc.data.entity.User is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.io.Serializable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:523) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue was the join column, which in this case was email, which was not an ID on the User table.

When the user_permission table was altered to include the user ID instead of user email, and join table name modified accordingly, it works.

**Working Example**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private int accountId;
private String name;
private String email;
private String password;
private boolean admin;

@ElementCollection
@Column(name="permission", nullable=false)
@CollectionTable(name = "user_permission", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: if the goal was to represent `permission_description` values in the `List<String>`  on the User entity, would it be as simple as changing the column annotation to:  `@Column(name="permission_description", nullable=false)` ?